# Freebase suggest - can it use a remote database?

Tags: jquery, freebase

I came across the Freebase suggest tool and i really like it. Is there a way to apply that to a site and have it use a remote database? I'm not finding out how to do that, I see in their API they have something called 'service_url' and 'service_path' which to me suggest that you can tell the plug-in to query a remote location.

Has anyone done this or is this plug-in strickly for the Freebase database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically, it's strictly for Freebase.

If you had another server which implemented all the relevant Freebase APIs, you could point it to that. However, no such server exists and doing that would be more work than reimplementing Suggest from scratch, so...